# Frequency Spectrum Analysis

Tags: signal-analysis, frequency-spectrum, dft, frequency-domain

[image]

How do you find the phase and inverse Fourier transform of this frequency spectrum?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: no it isn't....

Comment: The spectrum is usually complex. Sometimes the definition implies "magnitude", which is real, but in that case it would be positive. Perhaps you could clear this up a little from the context of the book? In this meant to be a Fourier representation of a signal which happens to be purely real?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The magnitude is given by $ {\left| X \left( f \right) \right|} $ hence it is 6.
2. Assuming all data is given in the graph, the function isn't complex it is only negative -> Phase is -180 degrees.
3. You should use its symmetry. Without over thinking it, It could be generated by a window on the center convolved with 2 deltas (Shifted) -> Sinc in time multiplied by 2 exponentials.

Comment: The magnitude is $|X(f)|$, not $|X(f)|^2$ (which is the squared magnitude). So its value is 6, not 36.

Comment: By the book you're correct. Yet usually this term is abused, and I assumed this to be the case :-) (Since otherwise it would be seem trivial). Anyhow, fixed it.